# Compositum of intersection fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-extensions

Suppose that $K_1$, $K_2$ and $K_3$ are finite Galois extensions of a field $k$. Let $(K_1 \cap K_3)(K_2 \cap K_3)$ be the compositum of $(K_1 \cap K_3)$ and $(K_2 \cap K_3)$. Is it always true that $$(K_1 \cap K_3)(K_2 \cap K_3) = K_1 K_2 \cap K_3?$$
I know that $(K_1 \cap K_3) \subseteq K_1 K_2 \cap K_3$ and $(K_2 \cap K_3) \subseteq K_1 K_2 \cap K_3$, so therefore $(K_1 \cap K_3)(K_2 \cap K_3) \subseteq K_1 K_2 \cap K_3$, but I am not sure if it is possible to show that $K_1 K_2 \cap K_3$ is the smallest field containing $(K_1 \cap K_3)$ and $(K_2 \cap K_3)$. Also, are the hypothesis of the fields being Galois or finite necessary here?

Comment: If $L=K_1K_2K_3$, $G=Gal(L/k)$, $N_i=Gal(L/K_i), i=1,2,3$ are the normal subgroups of $G$, then Galois correspondence associates $(N_1\cap N_2)N_3$ with $K_1K_2\cap K_3$ and $N_1N_3\cap N_2N_3$ with $(K_1\cap K_3)(K_2\cap K_3)$. It is easy to find instances where the subgroups $ (N_1\cap N_2)N_3$ and $N_1N_3\cap N_2N_3$ are not equal. For example with elementary abelian 2-groups it is easy to arrange both $N_1N_3$ and $N_2N_3$ to be equal to $C_2^3$ and simultaneously $N_1\cap N_2$ and $N_3$ to have only two elements. Nicolás found an even simpler counterexample.

Comment: Nice way of putting the problem! Let me add a naive way of thinking about this. The linear algebra equivalent is to compare
$$ (W_1 \cap W_3)+(W_2\cap W_3) \stackrel{?}{=} (W_1+W_2) \cap W_3, $$
where $W_i \subset V$ are subspaces. But now is clear that these might not be equal: take $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, and $W_i$ three different lines through the origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No! Let $k=\mathbb{Q}$, and consider $K_1=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}), K_2=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ and $K_3=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$. We have that $K_1 \cap K_3 = K_2 \cap K_3=\mathbb{Q}$, and so their compositum is also $\mathbb{Q}$. On the other hand, $K_1K_2 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ contains $\sqrt{6}$, and so
$$ K_1K_2 \cap K_3 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6}) \supsetneq \mathbb{Q} = (K_1 \cap K_3)(K_2 \cap K_3). $$

Comment: Good job! I was about start typing a similar (but slightly more complicated) counterexample. Thanks for saving me the trouble :-)